# Making a completely transparent object a light source?

Tags: light, emission

Down below is a rendered image of what I'm modelling (please excuse the fire flies). There is actually a RED spot light shining into the cube, and the refracted light shining into the cube is shined onto a jellyfish. The problem is that the light refracted by the cube and onto the jellyfish is WHITE not RED.

[image]

What I want to do is make a transparent material, like the the glass cube in the rendered image, that refracts so much light and color, in this case the red light, from its environment that is basically acts as a light source while still being completely transparent.

How would I go about doing this?

Here are the nodes that I used.

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, but the white light is probably coming from the emission shader in your material, with strength 100 it's likely blowing out the red spotlight. Maybe try turning it down and turning the spotlight strength up? Also, if you want the emitted light to be red, you have to change the color of the emission shader.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add an object as an emission and disable it's view in the render;

[image]

[image]

[image]